# postgres timestamp to specific date format in javascript file

Tags: javascript, postgresql, datepicker, timestamp

Timestamp 1489406400 after formatting it should show me 2017-03-08 07:00 AM
Can anyone please help me?

This timestamp is retrieved from postgres database and I have it available on the js file to get formatted. I used the datepicker but the day is not returned correctly I am getting 13 instead of 8 in the day value
3/13/2017   007:00 AM

```
function fDate(d){
  d= new Date(d * 1000);
  var D= [$.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy  ", d)],
```

....
}

what could be wrong? 
It is okay if someone know entirely new function to achieve the last result.

Comment: Looks like it is 13 Mar (http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)